Sentinel/Canary tool?
I occasionally notice connections to ports from unknown hosts, which definitely
have no business making such connections.  The services attached to those ports
have to be defensive against these clueless intrusions.
Is there a good "canary" tool I could attach to an unused port to
collect information about these miscreants?
I'll sweeten this post by adding two behaviors I've accidentally encountered, and would like to collect more information about.
#1 is a rapid series of 10-2o connections from a single IP address, which as far as I can tell just sit there, presumably waiting for the server to issue some greeting.

Aug 12 02:48:55 websockify-service-start: 195: got client connection from 206.168.34.36
Aug 12 02:48:55 websockify-service-start: 195: forking handler process
Aug 12 02:48:55 websockify-service-start: 196: got client connection from 206.168.34.36
Aug 12 02:48:55 websockify-service-start: 196: forking handler process
Aug 12 02:48:55 websockify-service-start: 197: got client connection from 206.168.34.36
Aug 12 02:48:55 websockify-service-start: 197: forking handler process
Aug 12 02:48:55 websockify-service-start: 198: got client connection from 206.168.34.36
Aug 12 02:48:55 websockify-service-start: 198: forking handler process
Aug 12 02:48:55 websockify-service-start: 199: got client connection from 206.168.34.36
Aug 12 02:48:55 websockify-service-start: 199: forking handler process
Aug 12 02:48:55 websockify-service-start: 200: got client connection from 206.168.34.36
Aug 12 02:48:55 websockify-service-start: 200: forking handler process
Aug 12 02:48:55 websockify-service-start: 201: got client connection from 206.168.34.36

The second is a probe that conveniently identifies itself as a port
scanner.
User-Agent: Expanse, a Palo Alto Networks company, searches across the global IPv4 space multiple times per day to identify customers presences on the Internet. If you would like to be excluded from our scans, please send IP addresses/domains to: scaninfo@paloaltonetworks.com

Answers to this question are likely to be different depending on whether you're talking about a Windows/Mac/Linux host. Please edit to include that info, thanks! It could also help to include examples of some of the services you're thinking about. For example, SSH has logging built-in already, so it already itself acts as a "canary" in that you can check its logs for all access attempts. For other less-featured services (or if you need to monitor a bunch of them in a unified view), a more general solution might be required.

The kind of webhost isn't relevant to the probes; I imagine there might be tools for all platforms; though mine is Linux.   Well known ports like SSH are targets of regular targeted attacks, which creates a very noisy environment.  I'm interested in in untargeted behavior that "innocent" web services will encounter.
